# DNS For home network

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, bind

I have a question. I want to set up DNS Server for my home network. The case is this: I made a server using Ubuntu 16.04 with LEMP stack and Virtualmin; so far so good. And now when I add Virtual server with a domain, for example, "devsite.dev", I have to add it in my `/etc/hosts` file. But I want to add the Ubuntu server IP-addr in my DNS config `/etc/resolv.conf` so I can access this domain from anywhere without changing the IP in my hosts file every time.

Server is Ubuntu Server 16.04 and I have already installed BIND9 (included in Virtualmin).

In summary: How can I configure BIND9 so I can access it from anywhere but query only the local zones ".dev" TLD's.

Comment: Hmm. Either way you"ll have to add the address of the server (`/etc/hosts` or `/etc/resolv.conf`) on every machine on which you want to use it. It is also not clear if you want to access this only from other machines in your home network or if you expect the server to be available to machines outside of your home in the Internet.

Comment: I expect the server to be available also outside of the home network. I was thinkg about VPN first connect to VPN then gain access, but the question is still here how can i avoid adding every website to hosts file...

Comment: Then you have to register your home internet address in some public DNS (dyndns.org could be a solution). But this is only half the answer, you need to  [open your home network to give access to the server inside](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-Port-Forwarding-on-a-Router) (and only the server...). But it is a lot safer to lease a VPS in the cloud (I pay $5/month for a LAMP server on Ubuntu 16.04).

Answer (score 0):

you need to make your DNS server as authoritative for any server/pc that want to access that devsite.dev (btw .dev is a real TLD by google https://nic.dev/) which could be confusing for the internet

i highly recommend using different TLD although it could work using any TLD having your own data inside the BIND authoritative for devsite.dev

also if you are on dynamic IP from your ISP there are a lot of dynamic IP services such as noip.com and others both free and paid.